# Getting a black screen after trying to resize an image

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am currently trying to resize a picture that I am downloading from the web and putting it into a JPanel.
First, I am using the following code to download the image from the web:

```
public static Image MSImageHigh(){
    URL imageUrl = null;
    try {
        imageUrl = new URL("http://www.hmdb.ca/labm/metabolites/" 
        + HMDB + "/ms/spectraH/" + HMDB + "H.png");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageUrl);
    return image;
}
```

Then I made a new method that resizes the image:

```
public static BufferedImage resizeImage() {
    final BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(300, 500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    final Graphics2D graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

    graphics2D.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    graphics2D.drawImage(MSImageHigh(), 0, 0, 200, 200, null);
    graphics2D.dispose();

    return bufferedImage;
}
```

This should produce s a new image that is resized to 200x200 px. What it in fact does is give me a black screen that is 200x200px in size. Btw, I also tried using TYPE_INT_ARGB instead of TYPE_INT_RGB, and this produces a totally transparent image, so that is not working either.

Comment: It is possible your image hasn't finished loading yet. This would explain why nothing is being painted. You can use a mediatracker to help fix this problem

Comment: What would happen if you use `ImageIO.read(imageUrl)` rather than `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageUrl);`?

Comment: @ControlAltDel  Better still, use `ImageIO.read(URL)` for a blocking method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `ImageIO.read(imageUrl)` instead of `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageUrl)` and that solved the problem. Thanks @Hovercraft Full Of Eels!